# Marketing Cloud Ampscript to output latest data within time period issue

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I have the below AMPScript that isn't quite right. What i want it to do is output data form a data extension that was added to the Data Extension within the last 24 hrs. I want to add the code to an email which will be run by an automation to send to a 3rd party once a day to give them the latest leads. We are based in New Zealand so to do the "formsubmitdate >= Now()" check I using the default value (Current date) in the data extension so uses the Marketing Cloud US Data Stamp but it doesn't seam to work. What am i missing?

If i edit the code i either get no rows found (Yet a recent test submission has been made) or it includes all submissions outside of the 24hrs

```
 
<tr> 
    <td style="width: 20%;"><b>Date Submitted</b></td> 
    <td style="width: 30%;"><b>First Name</b></td> 
    <td style="width: 30%;"><b>Last Name</b></td> 
    <td style="width: 20%;"><b>Email Address</b></td> 
    <td style="width: 20%;"><b>Contact Number</b></td> 
    <td style="width: 20%;"><b>Customer Comments/Product Interested in</b></td> 
</tr> 
%%[ 
var @rows, @row, @DateSubmitted, @FirstName, @LastName, @EmailAddress, @ContactPhoneNumber,  @Product, @formsubmitdate, @i
set @rows = lookuprows("leadform", "SubmitMethod","online")
set @chkDate = DateAdd(now(),-24,"h")
FOR @i = 1 to RowCount(@rows) DO
    set @DateSubmitted = field(Row(@rows,@i),'DateSubmitted')  
    set @FirstName = field(Row(@rows,@i),'FirstName')  
    set @LastName = field(Row(@rows,@i),'LastName')  
    set @EmailAddress = field(Row(@rows,@i),'EmailAddress')
    set @ContactPhoneNumber = field(Row(@rows,@i),'Contact Phone Number')
    set @Product = field(Row(@rows,@i),'Product')
    set @formsubmitdate = field(Row(@rows,@i),'formsubmitdate')
IF @formsubmitdate >= @chkDate THEN
]%% 
<tr>
    <td style="width: 20%;">%%=v(@DateSubmitted)=%%</td> 
    <td style="width: 20%;">%%=v(@FirstName)=%%</td> 
    <td style="width: 20%;">%%=v(@LastName)=%%</td>
    <td style="width: 20%;">%%=v(@EmailAddress)=%%</td>
    <td style="width: 20%;">%%=v(@ContactPhoneNumber)=%%</td>
    <td style="width: 20%;">%%=v(@Product)=%%</td>
</tr>
%%[
ELSE
RaiseError('No rows found')
]%%
%%[
ENDIF
NEXT @i
]%% 
</table>
```

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient way of doing this as you're pulling back all records where SubmitMethod = "Online" and from there you're going to need to loop through all records trying to find the small proportion that were added in the last 24hours. I'd consider either creating a Filtered Data Extension or use a SQL Query Activity to isolate only the records you're interested in and then send your email using this filtered data set.

Comment: @Macca The volumes are going to be very low, Im expecting a max of 100 records over a 4 week period. I have a number of these to setup all going to different suppliers so trying to find the simplest option without to much setup needed due to it being a one off campaign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it seems the value you passed as third argument into DateAdd() is not valid. Instead of "h", try "H".

Second, I would suggest setting a variable with the value for Now(). Then pass it into DateAdd() as first parameter.

```
set @currentDate = Now()
set @chkDate = DateAdd(@currentDate,-24,"H")
```